Batch Add GeoTiffs
I have several dozen GeoTiffs that I want to import, using the BlenderGIS plug-in I can add them one at a time with no problems, but when I select multiple, only the first loads. Any advice?
I have done so many google, and blender forum searches, if someone can even just suggest some better search terms I have no problem putting in more time.

My suggestion would be going to the "scripting" tab and see in the "info" what commands are used when you insert a geotiff. It's not guaranteed, but with some luck you could be able to see and copy that command for a list of images.

Thank you! Looks like I will be doing some deep python diving! Will report back.

Blender's main audience is animators and 3D artists. While geography stuff is possible, it remains relatively niche, and out of the common Blender tasks

@Duarte Farrajota Ramos, thanks for the reality check, it's pretty obvious to me now that I am is a GIS bubble, I'll make sure to be more patient and keep in mind not everything revolves around mapping.
